# Caption with one and half spacing and \linebreak command

Tags: captions, line-breaking

I want to justify my captions and set their spacing to one and half. At the same time I want to have a possibility to use `\linebreak` command within caption environment to split line at intended positions.

**Example**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=25mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength\parindent{0em}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Gas permeability and CO2-CH4 selectivity of PEI-GO MMM (Koolivand et al. [34])}
\label{tab:mmm1}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
    table is here
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I have a justified caption. I want to set one and half spacing. I also want to split the line after "PEI-GO MMM" and have the first line justified.

When using `caption` package with `font=onehalfspacing` option, the first line of the caption is indented. Second, the `\linebreak` command works with an error. The result looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=25mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength\parindent{0em}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[style=base,font=onehalfspacing]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Gas permeability and CO2-CH4 selectivity of PEI-GO MMM \linebreak (Koolivand et al. [34])}
\label{tab:mmm1}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
    table is here
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

with an `linebreak` error:

```
Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }. ... (Koolivand et al. \cite{Koolivand2014})}
Paragraph ended before \caption@ydblarg was complete. ... (Koolivand et al. \cite{Koolivand2014})}
```

Can anybody reproduce this error and suggest how to remove the first line indent and the error?

The log file of the full-length document is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Mlrs7zO1ZXgrmtg3WWk8lTO7CUXxNdC/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Even your first code snippet does not work as some package includes are missing (the `float` package for the `H` option and a package for the chemical formulas).

Comment: Float package was added. Chemical formula's package should not be important for this MWE.

Comment: don't do `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{center}`  use `\centering` not `\begin{center}` then you will nit need to add negative space to correct for the space that the  `center` environment adds.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Oops! Sorry, I misread the code. I'll replace my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the spacing around the caption using the lengths `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`.  Note that changes inside the table environment and inside the caption at local to each.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=25mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength\parindent{0em}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\hrule
\caption{\baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip
  Gas permeability and CO2-CH4 selectivity of PEI-GO MMM (Koolivand et al. [34])}
\label{tab:mmm1}
\hrule
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first line indent of the captions was due to `\setlength\abovedisplayskip{-10pt}` and `setlength\belowdisplayskip{10pt}` in my document. After removal of those rows the `caption` package works fine, except the `\linebreak` command.

Comment: @user46581 Use \\ instead of `\linebreak`. The caption package automatically replaces them with a space for the list entry.

Answer (score 1):

A few other solutions, with `copyrightbox`and `threeparttable`. For the spacing between caption and table, the `caption` package has the `skip=`key, and it is smart enough to swap  the values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`when the caption call is placed *before* the table code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry, copyrightbox, threeparttable}
\geometry{showframe, margin=25mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength\parindent{0em}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[style=base, font=onehalfspacing, format=hang, skip = 6pt]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Gas permeability and CO2-CH4 selectivity of PEI-GO MMM \\ (Koolivand et al. [34])\medskip}
\label{tab:mmm1}
\centering
\fbox{\makebox[0.5\linewidth]{ table is here}}
\end{table}
\vskip1cm
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\captionsetup{font=singlespacing, skip = 0pt}
\caption{Gas permeability and CO2-CH4 selectivity of PEI-GO MMM}
\label{tab:mmm2}
\copyrightbox[b]{\fbox{\makebox[0.5\linewidth]{ table is here}}}{(Koolivand et al. [34]}
\end{table}

\vskip1cm
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\captionsetup{font=singlespacing}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Gas permeability and CO2-CH4 selectivity of PEI-GO MMM\tnote{*} }
\label{tab:mmm3}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\fbox{\makebox[0.5\linewidth]{ table is here}}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\smallskip
  \item[*]Koolivand et al. [34]
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]